# How can I catch an error in jenkins and cause the job to fail

Tags: jenkins, groovy, cmake, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I have a multibranch pipeline that is used to build a pull request.
My pipeline is used to detect "both the current PR revision and the PR merged with the current target branch revision" and for build configuration I execute a groovy script.

My script is very simple:

```
stages {
    stage('[Stage 1] Build') {
        steps {
            script {
                try {
                    sh """#!/bin/bash
                    mkdir -p build
                    cd build
                    cmake ..
                    make
                    cd .."""
                } catch (err) {
                    error "[ERROR] Caught error when building branch: ${err}"
                    currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                }
            }
        }
    } /*End [Stage 1] Build */
}
post {
    success {
        script {
            try {
                echo "Build Number: ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
                echo "Branch name: ${env.GIT_BRANCH}"
            } catch (err) {
                error "[ERROR] Caught error trying to display build info: ${err}"
            } finally {
                cleanWs()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that the job is always successful even when the build is failing and I get errors. I can only see them in the console log, but otherwise my job is green and successful.

I also tried this approach:

```
stages {
    stage('[Stage 1] Build') {
        steps {
            script {
                catchError(buildResult: 'FAILURE', message: "build failed", stageResult: 'FAILURE')  {
                    sh """#!/bin/bash
                    mkdir -p build
                    cd build
                    cmake ..
                    make
                    cd .."""
                }                 }
        }
```

Still doesn't work.

Comment: I would suggest instead of catching errors to make the script fast fail, meaning that if any lines in the script fail, the entire script exits immediately with the exit code of that line and would fail the job. To do that you would remove the `try` and `catch` closures and change `#!/bin/bash` to `#!/bin/bash -e` (where the -e tells bash to turn on fail fast mode)

Comment: Actually, I've checked your code locally and it fails the build, if there is an error in Stage 1.

Comment: Most probably SH step returns exit code 0 and the last command "cd .." is successfully executed. It doesn't matter you can see errors if exit code is still 0.